# Disable Alt+C shortcut in KDE Konsole

Tags: kde, konsole

In KDE's Konsole, in a split view, `Alt+C` closes the last opened pane (view) for me. Unfortunately, this conflicts with my use of `Alt+C` to capitalise a word in Emacs. How do I turn off Konsole's behaviour for the `Alt+C` shortcut?

To be clearer: if I create a split view, `Alt+C` closes the last created view. If I create multiple split views, it *only* closese the last created view, then stops (that is, it doesn't recurse back to other views and closes those when using `Alt+C` after that). Once a view has been closed with `Alt+C`, I can use `Alt+C` as intended (in my case, within Emacs). So it appears `Alt+C` is somehow subsumed in the process of closing the last opened view (perhaps it is intended to be some form of "Cancel" the last action). `Alt+C` also doesn't interfere when there is a single view (but then, of course, I don't have a convenient side-by-side view of things).
My workaround, currently, is thus to open one extra view, close that with `Alt+C`, then be on my way.

I have not seen this behaviour anywhere else in KDE, nor when opening tabs instead of views in Konsole.

I have also not being able to find this shortcut in the Konsole keyboard shortcut settings, nor in the overall KDE keyboard shortcut settings. I am at loss where it is defined, and where it could be changed.

I would think this is a bug, but I can't find any mention of it elsewhere, except for a [lone Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hvlvqd/there_is_no_way_to_disable_altc_shortcut_in/). Is there any way to turn this off, and/or should I report this as a bug to KDE?

---

Version info:

Konsole 20.08.2
KDE Plasma 5.19.5, running on Ubuntu Studio 20.10.

Comment: I'd already be happy if someone could reproduce this behaviour, so that I know I didn't accidentally mess up my settings.